# Mutithreading accessing one std::map , will cause unsafe behavior?

Tags: c++

If more than one thread access one map object, but, I can make sure any of these threads accessing will not have the same key, and the accessing is just like:

```
//find value by key
//if find
// erase the object or change the value
//else
// add new object of the key
```

Will the operation cause synchronization problem？

Answer (score 5):

Yes, doing concurrent updates without proper synchronization may cause crashes, even if your threads access different keys: the `std::map` is based on trees, trees get rebalanced, so you can cause a write to a parent of a node with a seemingly unrelated key.

Moreover, it is not safe to perform read-only access concurrently with writing, or searching unlocked + locking on write: if you have threads that may update or delete nodes, you must lock out all readers before you write.

Comment: Thank you!Your answer makes me more clear about the question.

Answer (score 2):

You **will** have concurrency problems if any of the threads inserts into the tree. STL `map` is implemented using a red-black tree (or at least that's what I'm familiar with — I don't know whether the Standard mandates red-black tree). Red-black trees may be rebalanced upon insert, which would lead to all sorts of races between threads.

Read-only access (absolutely **no** writers) would be fine, but keep in mind `operator[]` is **not** read-only; it potentially adds a new element. You'd need to use the `find()` method, get the iterator, and derefence it yourself.

Comment: Thank you!It looks like that I must add synchronization locks to prevent the problem.

Comment: C++11 doesn't mandate the underlying data structure (any more than ISO C requires `qsort` to be a quicksort, despite what a lot of people may think) but maps are _very_ often done as red-blacks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the docs (ie, the ISO C++11 standard) say it's thread-safe (and they don't), then that's it. Period. It's not thread-safe.

There may be *implementations* of a std::map that would allow this but it's by no means portable.

Maps are often built on red-black trees or other auto-balancing data structures so that a modification to the structure (such as inserting or deleting a key) will cause rebalancing.

You should wrap read and write operations on the map with something like a mutex semaphore, to ensure that synchronisation is done correctly.